# Installing grunt locally went wrong?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I'm new with angularjs and I'm following a course to learn it but I got an issue while installing grunt locally, and this is the error I get:

```
C:\wamp\www\Projets\AngularJS>npm install grunt --save-dev
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "grunt" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package karma@1.3.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-jasmine@1.0.2 wants karma@*
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.2 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer gulp-karma@0.0.4 wants karma@>=0.10 <=0.13

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\wamp\www\Projets\AngularJS\npm-debug.log
```

I've executed the command line as administrator while doing this but still getting this error.
Thnx in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue that is solved by upgrading your npm with npm 3.

You can do it by :

```
npm install -g npm@3
```

or

```
upgrade your nodejs to nodejs 6 who come with npm 3 by default
```

From npm 3 the peerdependencies will generate WARN instead of ERR

Hope it will help you to solve your problem.